# Failed enrolling device with users accounts

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, wso2-iot

I can't enroll an android device with users credentials but with admin account, it works. I use credentials given in the invitation mail. Even with admin role for the user it doesn't works.

It says that "enrollment failed please contact administrator".

I use ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with wso2 emm version 2.2.0 and android 6.0

Can you help me please?

[image: With this error message]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the origin of the problem. This does not work when I try to register with an account that had already been created before and then deleted.
So I have to create new accounts each time with the new usernames.

I do not know if I made myself understood, but here is:
I create a "test" account, I have a device with this account on the agent. I'm unsubscribing. I delete the account. If I recreate the "test" account, registration will fail. I think it's just a bug.